# How to set a property of an extended class of a class stuck by itself?

Tags: php

### Exemple

**Path root**

- ClassA.php
- ClassB.php
- index.php

File: `classA.php`

```
class ClassA 
{
    public $returnA = null;
    public $errorA  = "Default error";

    function __construct
    {
       $this -> func_A();
    }

    public function func_A()
    {
        require_once 'classB.php';
        $obj = new ClassB;
        $obj -> func_B();
    }

}
```

File: `classB.php`

```
class ClassB extends ClassA
{
    public function func_B()
    {
       # attempt
       $this -> errorA = "Error func_B";
    }

}
```

File: `index.php`

```
require_once 'ClassA.php';

$obj = new ClassA;
echo ($obj -> returnA != null) ? $obj -> returnA : $obj -> errorA;
```

---

### Problem

My return from `index.php` is: "Default error".

What I expected: "Error func_B".

---

### Question

- Why does not a `errorA` property of `ClassA` change?
- What possible solutions?

Comment: property $errorA  is not static. so it is diiferent for each object. In this case, $obj in index.php and $obj  in function func_A() are not the same

Comment: @splash58 Got it. I think the solution would be to return an array or json, and process that return in ClassA !?

Comment: Or you can send context  to function ($this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only getting the default string because `func_A()` is creating a **new** instance of `ClassB`, calling a function on it then tossing it you (because you aren't returning it).

```
public function func_A()
{
    require_once 'classB.php';
    $obj = new ClassB; // New object instantiated
    $obj -> func_B(); // Function called on $obj

    // $obj dies here, as it is not returned and will go out of scope.
}
```

Essentially, `func_A()` performs nothing of value in your code above because it creates then throws away an object.

As for a proper solution, I would first ask *why* you want to encapsulate an extended class in the base class, as you are likely going about something wrong if this code is more than just a theoretical example.

Comment: The logic is ClassA, being a "master" class, it receives a call and processes according to the directory / file / class / method dynamically.
Then it will always call a class / method being this method, the last processing, and if it has error, it will set the property "errorA" of ClassA, if it has no errors, will set the property "data" of ClassA, for example.